# How to wrap c++ operator<< overload in Cython

Tags: c++, python-3.x, c++11, cython

In c++, I have `Cell` factory objects which return `Cells` that have `CellSocket` member variables. Don't worry about the details here, I'm just trying to illustrate the use-case for what I'm doing. The `CellSockets` can hold any type of variable with the help of `boost::any`. `CellSockets` have an overloaded `operator<<` that is basically an assignment operation, but with some other special stuff happening. So I can do stuff like this:

```
auto Adder = Cell::make_cell("Adder");
Adder.input_sockets[0] << "x";
Adder.input_sockets[1] << 1;
Adder.print(); //prints x+1
```

Now I'm trying to wrap the overloaded `operator<<` in Cython and running into some difficulty. I've exposed the overloaded operator in my `.pxd` like this:

```
cdef extern from "CellSocket.hpp" namespace "Quantum":
    cdef cppclass CellSocket:
        void operator<<[T](T)
```

Here's what this function signature looks like in the `CellSocket.hpp` file:

```
template<typename T>
void operator<<(const T& val)
```

In my `.pyx`, I try wrapping it into a python object like this:

```
cdef class QuCellSocket:
    cdef CellSocket thisinst

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisinst = CellSocket()

    def __lshift__(self, other):
        self.thisinst << other
```

This compiles fine, but this happens when I try to use it:

```
>>> from Quantum import QuCellSocket
>>> a = QuCellSocket()
>>> a << 'x'.encode(encoding='utf_8', errors='strict')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Quantum.pyx", line 20, in Quantum.QuCellSocket.__lshift__ (/Users/Thomas/Documents/workspace/Quantum/QuantumAPI/src/Quantum.cpp:967)
AttributeError: 'Quantum.QuCellSocket' object has no attribute 'thisinst'
```

So what seems to be happening is that the `__lshift__()` function does not have access to anything in the c++ code space. Any ideas on what is the best way to do this? I'm trying to carry over the `<<` assignment syntax into python.

I'm using cython 0.23.2, python 3.5, and gcc 5.2.0 on OSX El Capitan.

**Edit:**
So I've discovered I can get it working by doing something like this:

```
cdef class QuCellSocket:
    cdef CellSocket thisinst

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisinst = CellSocket()

    def lshift(self, other):
        if type(other) is int:
            self.thisinst << <int>other
        elif type(other) is float:
            self.thisinst << <float>other
        elif isinstance(other, bytes):
            self.thisinst << <string>other
        else:
            print("error: unsupported type!")

    def __lshift__(self, other):
        self.lshift(other)
```

But this is nasty. Any better ways?

Comment: I think you're hitting two issues: first that Cython expects arithmetic operators to be able to handle both `__lshift__(self,other)` and `__lshift__(other,self)` (which contradicts normal Python behaviour) and thus doesn't know the type of `self`. I think the solution you have of calling a member function should be OK with that.

Comment: Second is that Cython and templates don't interact too well, since you've got to decide at compile-time which template to call, but Python classes are decided at runtime. You've managed to solve that with the a bunch of if statements and type casts. You can make it a bit more automated with [fused types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html) but it doesn't work with `string`

Comment: DavidW, Thanks for pointing me to fused types. I wasn't aware of them. They definitely seem useful!

Comment: Yes - unfortunately it doesn't quite seem like they can get you to a clean solution, but it helps a bit.